# Preloading data into a backbone.js collection with django

Tags: python, django, backbone.js

I'm very new to Backbone.js (but not really to Django). I've set up a simple application to play around with backbone.js and Django (via djangorestframework), but I cannot seem to load server data into a collection.

Here's the views.py

```
from djangorestframework.mixins import ResponseMixin
from djangorestframework.renderers import DEFAULT_RENDERERS
from djangorestframework.compat import View
from djangorestframework.response import Response

class WeekView(ResponseMixin, View):
    """Gets and returns specific week, or current week if no week data provided."""
    renderers = DEFAULT_RENDERERS

    def get(self, request):
        response = Response(200, [{'day': x} for x in range(7)])
        return self.render(response)
```

Here's the backbone.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Backbone scripts */
    var Day = Backbone.Model.extend({
    });

    var Week = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Day,
        url: '/week'
    });

    var days = new Week;
    days.fetch();
    days.each(function(day) {
        console.log(day.get("day"));
    });
});
```

The console returns nothing.

If I log the days variable itself, I get something like:

```
> d
    _byCid: Object
    _byId: Object
    length: 7
    models: Array[7]
    __proto__: x
```

The view seems to be OK (calling /week returns a nicely formatted list of dictionaries of the type {'day': number}.

I'm sure the solution to preloading simple data into a collection is a very simple one, but I'm stumped...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is fetched asynchronously, so you need to respond to an event (like 'reset') or use a jquery deferred functionality (assuming jquery is used for the requests):

```
days.on("reset", function(days){
   console.log(days)l
});
days.fetch();
```

Or

```
$.when(days.fetch()).done(function(days){
  console.log(days);
}).error(function(){
  console.error("oops");
});
```